# Why I should For loop to read StratifiedShuffleSplit output?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am  using StratifiedShuffleSplit in python with n_splits=1,

I do not understand why I still need a for loop to get the output? Why the following code does not work?

```
split=StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1,test_size=0.2,random_state=42) 
train_index, test_index = split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"])
```

Here is the original code

```
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Comment: could you add the code you'd need for `n_splits=2`, or the working code for `n_splits=1`? That may help us answer.

Comment: My feeling says that the result is an array, and that a destructuring assignment (`split, = ...` - note the comma) will be the way to go

Comment: Because `split()` is a generator object in python using `yield`. So even when you have only single split, it needs to be iterated. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: @SillyFreak: I added the original code to my problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Vivek Kumar commented, the `split.split()` call in line two of your code returns an iterable (most likely a generator, not a list or something like that). Your non-working example tries to use the return value as if it wasn't.

Let's look with what kind of data your loop consumes:

```
for train_index, test_index in ...:
    ...
```

The `for` loop obviously requires an iterable. In addition, the `train_index, test_index` "destructures" each item in the iterable into two values, so each item has to be an iterable with exactly two elements. Usually, a tuple would be used for such cases.

So, the result of `split.split()` could look something like this:

```
[
    (a1, b1),
    (a2, b2),
    ...
]
```

Presumably, `n_splits=1` means that there will be only one pair `train_index, test_index` - at least that's what you seem to claim and need to verify. In that case, the result will be this:

```
[
    (a1, b1),
]
```

So *only one item* that is itself a *tuple with two items*. You now try to destructure that single item using `train_index, test_index = ...`, and this fails: the number of items does not match. You need to first extract the tuple.

There are two basic ways to get the tuple:

```
pair = split.split(...)[0]
pair, = split.split(...)
```

I would *strongly* suggest the second variant, because it fails when there is unexpectedly more than one item; the first variant would just silently discard extra items.

Then, you can destructure the tuple:

```
train_index, test_index = pair
```

Or, both in one step:

```
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1,test_size=0.2,random_state=42) 
(train_index, test_index), = split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"])
```